# Pinia store , router and component mangement in CDN

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, cdn, pinia

I'm working in a "complex" webapp featuring  :Vue + Vuetify + Pinia + router.
I develop it on VSC with VUE CLI, but now for several reason, I need to put the project in Google AppScript so it would be excuted on gas and access to "securised data" on google workspace with a *.gs API.

So I would like to transform the code into UMD/CDN mode, so I can :

- easily transferts modification, new components from the webapp to the GAS version
- Plug Pinia store to google fonction in another files in the same project (via google.script.run.withSuccessHandler)
- keep component dividing
- access to pinia store(s) in the component
- Apply vuetify theming to all component

So far I have the following page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" class="md-scrollbar">

<head>
    <title>Mon Application Vue.js</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app" class="main">
        <v-app>

            <app-bar />

            <v-main class="main">
                <template>
                    <v-container>

                        <v-row class="my-10 mx-4"></v-row>
                        <v-container class="grow d-flex flex-column flex-nowrap ">
                            <v-row class="" min-heigth="100%">
                                <v-col cols="12" class="my-16 mx-4 d-flex justify-center">
                                    <v-img max-height="550" max-width="845"
                                        src="xxx">
                                    </v-img>
                                </v-col>

                            </v-row>
                            <v-row class="my-10 mx-4"></v-row>
                            <v-row justify="center" class="">
                                <v-btn v-for="(item1,index1) in firstPageBtn" :key="index1"
                                    class="primary_lightest black--text  text-center d-flex flex-column mx-5" shaped
                                    height="auto">
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-center text-center flex-column ma-10">
                                        <v-img class="d-flex justify-center text-center " :src="item1.img" contain
                                            :aspect-ratio="1.0" max-width="75" max-height="75"></v-img>
                                        <div class="text-h6 mt-2">{{item1.name}}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </v-btn>
                            </v-row>
                        </v-container>
                </template>
            </v-main>
        </v-app>
        <div>

            <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
            <script type="application/javascript"
                src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

            <script src="https://unpkg.com/@vue/composition-api"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia"></script>

            <script>

                const navigationStore = Pinia.defineStore('navigation', {
                    state: () => ({
                        tab: "first", //Situation de v-tab 
                        drawer: true, //affichage du menu
                        navigation: [ //listes des tabs
                            {
                                title: "Acceuil",
                                href: "#Acceuil",
                                icon: "mdi-menu",
                                description: "Ouvrir la barre de menu (Cliquez en dehors de la barre de navigation pour la fermer sans changer de page)"
                            }, {
                                title: "page1",
                                href: "#page1",
                                icon: "mdi-sitemap",
                                description: "page1"
                            }, {
                                title: "Summary",
                                href: "#summary",
                                icon: "mdi-code-not-equal",
                                description: "page2"
                            }, 
                        ],
                    }),
                    getters: {

                    },
                    actions: {
                        slide(payload) {
                            this.tab = payload
                        },
                        hideReveal() {
                            this.drawer = !this.drawer
                        },
                    },
                })

                const appBar = {
                    template: `
    <v-app-bar app class="appbar bg-primary primary--text pa-1align-content-start pa-1">
      <v-icon right @click="hideReveal">mdi-menu </v-icon>
        <v-img alt="xxx"  class="ma-2 ml-12" max-height="10rem" max-width="10rem"
            lazy-src="xxx"
            src="xxx"></v-img>
        <v-toolbar-title center class="text-h4 text-h6-sm text-h6-md">Title</v-toolbar-title>    
          
    </v-app-bar>`,                
                }

                const app = new Vue({
                    el: "#app",
                    data: {
                        firstPageBtn: [
                            { name: "XXX", img: "XXX", link: "" },
                            { name: "XXX", img: "XXX", link: "" },
                            { name: "XXX", img: "XXX", link: "" }
                        ]
                    },
                    components: {
                        appBar: appBar
                    },
                    pinia: Pinia.createPinia(),

                    computed: {
                    },
                    methods: {
                    },
                    vuetify: new Vuetify({
                        theme: {
                            themes: {
                                light: {
                                    primary: "#04B074",
                                    secondary: "#00205B",
                                    sucess: "#84bd00",
                                    accent: "#fe5000",
                                    error: "#e4002b",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    }),
                });
               app.components('appbar')

            </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can i now access to pinia Store and theme from component AppBar

Comment: It's unclear what's the relation between GAS and CDN. What exactly does prevent you from building an app? And what's the actual question.

Comment: I can't use build app because i need to code a store inside the appscript (can not use google API) to get info from gsheet

Comment: It don't use GAS myself but this looks like XY problem.  In your current implementation you'll have to expose everything you previously imported to global scope and use global vars universally, which is a really bad move. Mangling a properly built modular app looks like an odd workaround. There could be a way for the bundled app to be imported into GS script or be loaded in another place interact with it in some way

Comment: Yeah, I know this is not the best solution, it's just what i'm allowed to do to serve the webapp on securised cloud

Comment: I'm not sure what's the limitation. Both lib CDN builds and Webpack build are JS scripts. If you can load one, you can load another. I'd suggest to investigate your options before jumping to the least preferable one.